# Woocommerce show a div when variation product is selected

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have configured a variation product with 4 options:

```
 - 1: 240x400cm
 - 2: 400x400cm
 - 3: 500x600cm
 - 4: Custom Work
```

What I want is that my script in jQuery check what value is selected as option at the variation product.

Example:

```
If value = "custom work" show div.
```

I can't find a solution at this moment to check the enabled/selected value of the variation option. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this will help you-

```
<select id="colorselector">
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> .A... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> ..B. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> ...C </div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#colorselector').change(function(){
      if(jQuery('#colorselector').val() == 'blue'){
        jQuery('#blue').show();
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you send me your website url

Comment: jQuery('#pa_afmeting').change(function(){
   if(jQuery('#pa_afmeting').val() == 'maatwerk'){
  jQuery('#your_div_id').show();
   }
 });